# Flutter Future & Sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future, sqflite

I use Sqflite to save data (for example a name of a person).
With this function I get the data of the DB:

```
Future<List<Student>> getStudentList() async {
await openDb();
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _database.query('student', orderBy: 'name ASC'); 
return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
  return Student(
      id: maps[i]['id'], name: maps[i]['name']);
});
}
```

At the start I want to add the names in the DB into a List.

```
  @override
void initState() {
foo();
//userList.add(User('Test1', 'Test, false));
//userList.add(User('test2', 'test', false));
userList
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.name.toLowerCase()));
filterList();
searchController.addListener(() {
  filterList();
});
super.initState();
}
```

This is how I defined foo() where I want to get the data out of the DB:

```
Future foo() async{ 
studlist = await dbmanager.getStudentList();
 var tl = studlist.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < tl; i++) {
  userList.add(User(studlist[i].name, 'Test', false));
  // print('${studlist[i].name}');
 // print('$i');
}
}
```

The problem is, that this function doesn't save anything in the List.
If I use in `void initState()` this test code instead of foo(), it works:

```
userList.add(User('Test1', 'Test, false));
userList.add(User('test2', 'test', false));
```

So something must be wrong with `foo()`.
I also added  `print('${studlist[i].name}'); print('$i');` in the for loop to test, if `studlist[i]` works, and it printed out every name.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `foo` method is async and you're not awaiting it. So, the `initState` calling code is returned to as soon as that await is hit and before your `userList` adds. The adds will happen eventually, but you're `initState` logic is running before that happens. For this to work, you need to wait until `foo` has completed. You can't just go and make `initState` async and await `foo`, but you can do your work after the `Future` is complete by using then `then` method.

```
void initState() {
  foo().then((result) {
      userList
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.name.toLowerCase()));
    filterList();
    searchController.addListener(() {
      filterList();
    });
    setState(() => {});
  });

  super.initState();
}
```

Now your `build` will need to handle the loading case in which you don't yet have users, but this code should populate your `userList` and rebuild your view with the users. If this gets more complex, you may want to consider using [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) which is more setup for dealing with this async behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. Also your explanation was really helpful!